# Golang http handler testing with inner functions

Tags: go, testing, struct, interface

I want to build a testing part for my http handlers, and I want to use the http handler functions how they are, but I want to have separate functions that mock the db part of the handling. What I have in mind is something like:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "testing"
)

// DB functions
type UserDBFunctions interface {
    InsertUser() string
}

type UserDB struct {
}

func (u UserDB) InsertUser() string {
    return "hello"
}

// http handler functions
type UserHandlerFunctions interface {
    Register() string
}

type UserHandler struct {
    userDb *UserDB
}

func newUserHandler() UserHandler {
    return UserHandler{userDb: new(UserDB)}
}

func (u UserHandler) Register() string {
    str := u.userDb.InsertUser()
    return str + " world"
}

func main() {
    var i UserHandlerFunctions = newUserHandler()
    str :=  i.Register()
    log.Println(str)
}

// test functions
type FakeUserDBFunctions interface {
    InsertUser() string
}

type FakeUserDB struct {
}

func (u FakeUserDB) InsertUser() string {
    return "bye"
}

func newFakeUserHandler() UserHandler {
    return UserHandler{userDb: *UserDB(&FakeUserDB{})}
}

func TestRegisterUser(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("register user", func(t *testing.T) {
        var i UserHandlerFunctions = newFakeUserHandler()
        str := i.Register()
        log.Println(str)
    })
}
```

So the first interface is for the real db functions, then there is the http handler which calls the db function and below the main() function there should be the tests with a mockup of the db function. But this part doesn't work. How do I replace the real interface in the newUserHandler by a mockup.

I would really appreciate help.

Comment: I think you're doing it slightly wrong. IMO a more classic approach is to have an interface "user database" which has to be implemented by your "real" `UserDB` type and some stub/mock/fake type which is instantiated in the tests. The rest of your code—a particular HTTP server mux or whatever—gets supplied an instance of a type implementing that "user database" interface at construction time, and is completely oblivious about the real dynamic type of the instance it works with; the mux's handlers—too. Then you exercise the handlers and inspect the results as appropriate.

Comment: I can't really imagine your structure.

I want to have a userHandler, which has multiple handler functions like `func (u User) RegisterUser(rw ..., r ...) {...}` and the userHandler struct gets initialised with a service struct, which I use for database initialisation, AuthMiddleware etc. and which I can reuse for all services.

Now I have separated the database logic from the http handling like checking for values etc.

Comment: I want to test the http handlers without using the database. But I only need the above mentioned service struct in the db part, which I want to mock for the http handler testing. That's why I want to build a new FakeUserDB.

Comment: Here an example: https://play.golang.org/p/sgV3sni0BDd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UseHandler shall use UserDBFunctions instead of UserDB.

```
type UserHandler struct {
    userDb UserDBFunctions
}
```

Here is the modified one https://play.golang.org/p/nLiaomKA2NH

Comment: Thank you very much, that was an easy fix. I can not thank you enough, I wasn't able to fix it myself. 

Comment: How could I access another struct in UserDB? In my example it is empty, but in my real code it isn't and I have to call `i.userDb.newStruct...`.

Comment: I am not sure I understood the question, bit is this what you are looking for? https://play.golang.org/p/myE1H9FtLWo

Comment: Not quite, I don't need to u.storage.StoreData("rec1") inside the InsertUser function, but I need to call in your example u.userDb.storage.StoreData() inside the main function.

Comment: Like this: https://play.golang.org/p/sgV3sni0BDd